# how to not accept the value out of range values inside html input box after setting min and max value

Tags: javascript, html, range, web-deployment

```
      <label for="interest-rate">Interest Rate</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="interestRate"
        name="loancalc"
        placeholder="0"
        min="0"
        max="30"
        class="validateMinMax"
        oninput="this.form.interestRangeRate.value = this.value"

        ;
      /><span class="input-group-text">%</span>
      <br />
      <input
        type="range"
        name="loancalc"
        id="interestRangeRate"
        min="0"
        max="30"
        oninput="this.form.interestRate.value=this.value"
        ;
      />
```

inside input box if i enter 40 which is more than maximum value but still it is accepting after pressing enter button it is validating but if input value is more than max then it should pass max value.

Comment: Look into <form> HTML tag. Moreover, you can also check the value before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add additional validation of data on `submit` action. This is how html input is working. You can try to use custom `number input` library to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `oninput="this.form.interestRate.value=this.value` with `oninput="checkValue(this);`

this should fix it!

[here](https://codepen.io/jankees/pen/WNZjOgY) is a codepen.io link!

Comment: oninput="this.form.interestRate.value=this.value is used for input from range sliding bar. this can not be replaced with checkValue(this)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a read of [HTML5 Constraint Validation](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

```
<input  type="number" id="interestRate" pattern="[0-30]"  />
<script>
    document.getElementById('interestRate').validity.patternMismatch;
</script>
```